# Como enviar dados por arquivo XML através de uma integração via API para o servidor

Tags: php, xml, api

Estou utilizando o Framework Codeigniter e tentando fazer uma integração com sistema via API usando XML.

Tenho que fazer um envio de arquivo com parâmetros XML para um servidor via post. Basicamente o servidor tem que receber uma string com data=conteúdo xml.

Testei com o Advanced Rest Cliente (extensão do chrome que simula um envio POST) e funcinou perfeitamente, ou seja, o servidor está OK.

quando jogo no código do PHP ele não consegue enviar o XML e retorna erro 400 (bad request).

Alguém tem alguma dica?

Segue código:

```
<?php
$query = $this -> db -> query('SELECT token FROM configuracao LIMIT 1');
$row = $query -> row_array();
$token = $row['token'];

$conteudoXML= "data=";
$conteudoXML.= "<schedule>";
$conteudoXML.= "<alternativeIdentifier>1234567</alternativeIdentifier>";
$conteudoXML.= "<observation>1234567</observation>";
$conteudoXML.= "<agent><id>220876</id></agent>";
$conteudoXML.= "<serviceLocal><alternativeIdentifier>teste</alternativeIdentifier></serviceLocal>";
$conteudoXML.= "<activitiesOrigin>4</activitiesOrigin>";
$conteudoXML.= "<date>2015-11-25</date>";
$conteudoXML.= "<hour>00:00</hour>";
$conteudoXML.= "<activityRelationship>";
$conteudoXML.= "<activity><alternativeIdentifier>corretiva</alternativeIdentifier></activity>";
$conteudoXML.= "</activityRelationship>";
$conteudoXML.= "</schedule>";

$url = "http://api.umov.me/CenterWeb/api/$token/schedule.xml";
$xml_str = $conteudoXML;


$post_data = array('xml' => $xml_str);
$stream_options = array(
'http' => array(
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' . "\r\n",
    'content' =>  http_build_query($post_data)));

$context  = stream_context_create($stream_options);
$response = file_get_contents($url, null, $context);
?>
```

Comment: Você quer enviar dados, ou quer consumir os dados do servidor? Não ficou claro pra mim.

Comment: Na verdade acontece os 2, primeiro ele envia uma requisição, depois ele busca o resultado (se deu certo ou não). Consegui resolver com o crul

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver...

Troquei o método para Curl (tive que instalar porque no meu servidor não estava disponível).

No final ficou assim:

```
//setting the curl parameters.
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);

    if (curl_errno($ch)) 
{
    // moving to display page to display curl errors
      echo curl_errno($ch) ;
      echo curl_error($ch);
} 
else 
{
    //getting response from server
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
     print_r($response);
     curl_close($ch);
}
```